# The drop down menu does not work on the mobile screen while using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please understand that I am a beginner and I am not familiar with English.
I used a template but the dropdown works on the computer screen but not on the mobile screen. The pairs of tags are correct and I'll briefly show you the code.

This is the link to the template I used.
https://colorlib.com/wp/template/locals-directory/

- header part

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/my/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/my/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/my/css/flaticon.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/my/css/nice-select.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/my/css/owl.carousel.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/my/css/magnific-popup.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/my/css/slicknav.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/my/css/style.css" type="text/css">
 <header class="header-section">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="/lmain"><img src="/my/img/main_logo.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <nav class="main-menu mobile-menu navbar">
                <ul>
                   <li class="nav-item active">
      <a href="/lmain" class="nav-link">Home</a>
       </li>
                   <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">  
        Hair Style
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink" 
      style="background-color:#2E2E2E">
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="/man" style="background-color:#2E2E2E">Man</a>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="/woman"style="background-color:#2E2E2E">Woman</a>
      </div>
     </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">Trend</a>
     </li>
</ul>
</nav>

<div id="mobile-menu-wrap"></div>
</div>
</header>
```

- footer part

```html
<!-- Js Plugins -->
    <script src="/my/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/my/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/my/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/my/js/jquery.slicknav.js"></script>
    <script src="/my/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/my/js/jquery.nice-select.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/my/js/mixitup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/my/js/main.js"></script>
```

- jquery.slicknav.js

```js
;(function ($, document, window) {
    var
    // default settings object.
        defaults = {
            label: 'MENU',
            duplicate: true,
            duration: 200,
            easingOpen: 'swing',
            easingClose: 'swing',
            closedSymbol: '&#9658;',
            openedSymbol: '&#9660;',
            prependTo: 'body',
            appendTo: '',
            parentTag: 'a',
            closeOnClick: false,
            allowParentLinks: false,
            nestedParentLinks: true,
            showChildren: false,
            removeIds: true,
            removeClasses: false,
            removeStyles: false,
   brand: '',
            animations: 'jquery',
            init: function () {},
            beforeOpen: function () {},
            beforeClose: function () {},
            afterOpen: function () {},
            afterClose: function () {}
        },
        mobileMenu = 'slicknav',
        prefix = 'slicknav',

        Keyboard = {
            DOWN: 40,
            ENTER: 13,
            ESCAPE: 27,
            LEFT: 37,
            RIGHT: 39,
            SPACE: 32,
            TAB: 9,
            UP: 38,
        };

    function Plugin(element, options) {
        this.element = element;

        // jQuery has an extend method which merges the contents of two or
        // more objects, storing the result in the first object. The first object
        // is generally empty as we don't want to alter the default options for
        // future instances of the plugin
        this.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        // Don't remove IDs by default if duplicate is false
        if (!this.settings.duplicate && !options.hasOwnProperty("removeIds")) {
          this.settings.removeIds = false;
        }

        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = mobileMenu;

        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype.init = function () {
        var $this = this,
            menu = $(this.element),
            settings = this.settings,
            iconClass,
            menuBar;

        // clone menu if needed
        if (settings.duplicate) {
            $this.mobileNav = menu.clone();
        } else {
            $this.mobileNav = menu;
        }

        // remove IDs if set
        if (settings.removeIds) {
          $this.mobileNav.removeAttr('id');
          $this.mobileNav.find('*').each(function (i, e) {
              $(e).removeAttr('id');
          });
        }

        // remove classes if set
        if (settings.removeClasses) {
            $this.mobileNav.removeAttr('class');
            $this.mobileNav.find('*').each(function (i, e) {
                $(e).removeAttr('class');
            });
        }

        // remove styles if set
        if (settings.removeStyles) {
            $this.mobileNav.removeAttr('style');
            $this.mobileNav.find('*').each(function (i, e) {
                $(e).removeAttr('style');
            });
        }

        // styling class for the button
        iconClass = prefix + '_icon';

        if (settings.label === '') {
            iconClass += ' ' + prefix + '_no-text';
        }

        if (settings.parentTag == 'a') {
            settings.parentTag = 'a href="#"';
        }

        // create menu bar
        $this.mobileNav.attr('class', prefix + '_nav');
        menuBar = $('<div class="' + prefix + '_menu"></div>');
  if (settings.brand !== '') {
   var brand = $('<div class="' + prefix + '_brand">'+settings.brand+'</div>');
   $(menuBar).append(brand);
  }
        $this.btn = $(
            ['<' + settings.parentTag + ' aria-haspopup="true" role="button" tabindex="0" class="' + prefix + '_btn ' + prefix + '_collapsed">',
                '<span class="' + prefix + '_menutxt">' + settings.label + '</span>',
                '<span class="' + iconClass + '">',
                    '<span class="' + prefix + '_icon-bar"></span>',
                    '<span class="' + prefix + '_icon-bar"></span>',
                    '<span class="' + prefix + '_icon-bar"></span>',
                '</span>',
            '</' + settings.parentTag + '>'
            ].join('')
        );
        $(menuBar).append($this.btn);
        if(settings.appendTo !== '') {
            $(settings.appendTo).append(menuBar);
        } else {
            $(settings.prependTo).prepend(menuBar);
        }
        menuBar.append($this.mobileNav);

        // iterate over structure adding additional structure
        var items = $this.mobileNav.find('li');
        $(items).each(function () {
            var item = $(this),
                data = {};
            data.children = item.children('ul').attr('role', 'menu');
            item.data('menu', data);

            // if a list item has a nested menu
            if (data.children.length > 0) {

                // select all text before the child menu
                // check for anchors

                var a = item.contents(),
                    containsAnchor = false,
                    nodes = [];

                $(a).each(function () {
                    if (!$(this).is('ul')) {
                        nodes.push(this);
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }

                    if($(this).is("a")) {
                        containsAnchor = true;
                    }
                });

                var wrapElement = $(
                    '<' + settings.parentTag + ' role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="-1" class="' + prefix + '_item"/>'
                );

                // wrap item text with tag and add classes unless we are separating parent links
                if ((!settings.allowParentLinks || settings.nestedParentLinks) || !containsAnchor) {
                    var $wrap = $(nodes).wrapAll(wrapElement).parent();
                    $wrap.addClass(prefix+'_row');
                } else
                    $(nodes).wrapAll('<span class="'+prefix+'_parent-link '+prefix+'_row"/>').parent();

                if (!settings.showChildren) {
                    item.addClass(prefix+'_collapsed');
                } else {
                    item.addClass(prefix+'_open');
                }

                item.addClass(prefix+'_parent');

                // create parent arrow. wrap with link if parent links and separating
                var arrowElement = $('<span class="'+prefix+'_arrow">'+(settings.showChildren?settings.openedSymbol:settings.closedSymbol)+'</span>');

                if (settings.allowParentLinks && !settings.nestedParentLinks && containsAnchor)
                    arrowElement = arrowElement.wrap(wrapElement).parent();

                //append arrow
                $(nodes).last().after(arrowElement);


            } else if ( item.children().length === 0) {
                 item.addClass(prefix+'_txtnode');
            }

            // accessibility for links
            item.children('a').attr('role', 'menuitem').click(function(event){
                //Ensure that it's not a parent
                if (settings.closeOnClick && !$(event.target).parent().closest('li').hasClass(prefix+'_parent')) {
                        //Emulate menu close if set
                        $($this.btn).click();
                    }
            });

            //also close on click if parent links are set
            if (settings.closeOnClick && settings.allowParentLinks) {
                item.children('a').children('a').click(function (event) {
                    //Emulate menu close
                    $($this.btn).click();
                });

                item.find('.'+prefix+'_parent-link a:not(.'+prefix+'_item)').click(function(event){
                    //Emulate menu close
                        $($this.btn).click();
                });
            }
        });

        // structure is in place, now hide appropriate items
        $(items).each(function () {
            var data = $(this).data('menu');
            if (!settings.showChildren){
                $this._visibilityToggle(data.children, null, false, null, true);
            }
        });

        // finally toggle entire menu
        $this._visibilityToggle($this.mobileNav, null, false, 'init', true);

        // accessibility for menu button
        $this.mobileNav.attr('role','menu');

        // outline prevention when using mouse
        $(document).mousedown(function(){
            $this._outlines(false);
        });

        $(document).keyup(function(){
            $this._outlines(true);
        });

        // menu button click
        $($this.btn).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $this._menuToggle();
        });

        // click on menu parent
        $this.mobileNav.on('click', '.' + prefix + '_item', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $this._itemClick($(this));
        });

        // check for keyboard events on menu button and menu parents
        $($this.btn).keydown(function (e) {
            var ev = e || event;

            switch(ev.keyCode) {
                case Keyboard.ENTER:
                case Keyboard.SPACE:
                case Keyboard.DOWN:
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if (ev.keyCode !== Keyboard.DOWN || !$($this.btn).hasClass(prefix+'_open')){
                        $this._menuToggle();
                    }
                    
                    $($this.btn).next().find('[role="menuitem"]').first().focus();
                    break;
            }

            
        });

        $this.mobileNav.on('keydown', '.'+prefix+'_item', function(e) {
            var ev = e || event;

            switch(ev.keyCode) {
                case Keyboard.ENTER:
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $this._itemClick($(e.target));
                    break;
                case Keyboard.RIGHT:
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if ($(e.target).parent().hasClass(prefix+'_collapsed')) {
                        $this._itemClick($(e.target));
                    }
                    $(e.target).next().find('[role="menuitem"]').first().focus();
                    break;
            }
        });

        $this.mobileNav.on('keydown', '[role="menuitem"]', function(e) {
            var ev = e || event;

            switch(ev.keyCode){
                case Keyboard.DOWN:
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var allItems = $(e.target).parent().parent().children().children('[role="menuitem"]:visible');
                    var idx = allItems.index( e.target );
                    var nextIdx = idx + 1;
                    if (allItems.length <= nextIdx) {
                        nextIdx = 0;
                    }
                    var next = allItems.eq( nextIdx );
                    next.focus();
                break;
                case Keyboard.UP:
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var allItems = $(e.target).parent().parent().children().children('[role="menuitem"]:visible');
                    var idx = allItems.index( e.target );
                    var next = allItems.eq( idx - 1 );
                    next.focus();
                break;
                case Keyboard.LEFT:
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if ($(e.target).parent().parent().parent().hasClass(prefix+'_open')) {
                        var parent = $(e.target).parent().parent().prev();
                        parent.focus();
                        $this._itemClick(parent);
                    } else if ($(e.target).parent().parent().hasClass(prefix+'_nav')){
                        $this._menuToggle();
                        $($this.btn).focus();
                    }
                    break;
                case Keyboard.ESCAPE:
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $this._menuToggle();
                    $($this.btn).focus();
                    break;    
            }
        });

        // allow links clickable within parent tags if set
        if (settings.allowParentLinks && settings.nestedParentLinks) {
            $('.'+prefix+'_item a').click(function(e){
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            });
        }
    };

    //toggle menu
    Plugin.prototype._menuToggle = function (el) {
        var $this = this;
        var btn = $this.btn;
        var mobileNav = $this.mobileNav;

        if (btn.hasClass(prefix+'_collapsed')) {
            btn.removeClass(prefix+'_collapsed');
            btn.addClass(prefix+'_open');
        } else {
            btn.removeClass(prefix+'_open');
            btn.addClass(prefix+'_collapsed');
        }
        btn.addClass(prefix+'_animating');
        $this._visibilityToggle(mobileNav, btn.parent(), true, btn);
    };

    // toggle clicked items
    Plugin.prototype._itemClick = function (el) {
        var $this = this;
        var settings = $this.settings;
        var data = el.data('menu');
        if (!data) {
            data = {};
            data.arrow = el.children('.'+prefix+'_arrow');
            data.ul = el.next('ul');
            data.parent = el.parent();
            //Separated parent link structure
            if (data.parent.hasClass(prefix+'_parent-link')) {
                data.parent = el.parent().parent();
                data.ul = el.parent().next('ul');
            }
            el.data('menu', data);
        }
        if (data.parent.hasClass(prefix+'_collapsed')) {
            data.arrow.html(settings.openedSymbol);
            data.parent.removeClass(prefix+'_collapsed');
            data.parent.addClass(prefix+'_open');
            data.parent.addClass(prefix+'_animating');
            $this._visibilityToggle(data.ul, data.parent, true, el);
        } else {
            data.arrow.html(settings.closedSymbol);
            data.parent.addClass(prefix+'_collapsed');
            data.parent.removeClass(prefix+'_open');
            data.parent.addClass(prefix+'_animating');
            $this._visibilityToggle(data.ul, data.parent, true, el);
        }
    };

    // toggle actual visibility and accessibility tags
    Plugin.prototype._visibilityToggle = function(el, parent, animate, trigger, init) {
        var $this = this;
        var settings = $this.settings;
        var items = $this._getActionItems(el);
        var duration = 0;
        if (animate) {
            duration = settings.duration;
        }
        
        function afterOpen(trigger, parent) {
            $(trigger).removeClass(prefix+'_animating');
            $(parent).removeClass(prefix+'_animating');

            //Fire afterOpen callback
            if (!init) {
                settings.afterOpen(trigger);
            }
        }
        
        function afterClose(trigger, parent) {
            el.attr('aria-hidden','true');
            items.attr('tabindex', '-1');
            $this._setVisAttr(el, true);
            el.hide(); //jQuery 1.7 bug fix

            $(trigger).removeClass(prefix+'_animating');
            $(parent).removeClass(prefix+'_animating');

            //Fire init or afterClose callback
            if (!init){
                settings.afterClose(trigger);
            } else if (trigger == 'init'){
                settings.init();
            }
        }

        if (el.hasClass(prefix+'_hidden')) {
            el.removeClass(prefix+'_hidden');
             //Fire beforeOpen callback
            if (!init) {
                settings.beforeOpen(trigger);
            }
            if (settings.animations === 'jquery') {
                el.stop(true,true).slideDown(duration, settings.easingOpen, function(){
                    afterOpen(trigger, parent);
                });
            } else if(settings.animations === 'velocity') {
                el.velocity("finish").velocity("slideDown", {
                    duration: duration,
                    easing: settings.easingOpen,
                    complete: function() {
                        afterOpen(trigger, parent);
                    }
                });
            }
            el.attr('aria-hidden','false');
            items.attr('tabindex', '0');
            $this._setVisAttr(el, false);
        } else {
            el.addClass(prefix+'_hidden');

            //Fire init or beforeClose callback
            if (!init){
                settings.beforeClose(trigger);
            }

            if (settings.animations === 'jquery') {
                el.stop(true,true).slideUp(duration, this.settings.easingClose, function() {
                    afterClose(trigger, parent)
                });
            } else if (settings.animations === 'velocity') {
                
                el.velocity("finish").velocity("slideUp", {
                    duration: duration,
                    easing: settings.easingClose,
                    complete: function() {
                        afterClose(trigger, parent);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };

    // set attributes of element and children based on visibility
    Plugin.prototype._setVisAttr = function(el, hidden) {
        var $this = this;

        // select all parents that aren't hidden
        var nonHidden = el.children('li').children('ul').not('.'+prefix+'_hidden');

        // iterate over all items setting appropriate tags
        if (!hidden) {
            nonHidden.each(function(){
                var ul = $(this);
                ul.attr('aria-hidden','false');
                var items = $this._getActionItems(ul);
                items.attr('tabindex', '0');
                $this._setVisAttr(ul, hidden);
            });
        } else {
            nonHidden.each(function(){
                var ul = $(this);
                ul.attr('aria-hidden','true');
                var items = $this._getActionItems(ul);
                items.attr('tabindex', '-1');
                $this._setVisAttr(ul, hidden);
            });
        }
    };

    // get all 1st level items that are clickable
    Plugin.prototype._getActionItems = function(el) {
        var data = el.data("menu");
        if (!data) {
            data = {};
            var items = el.children('li');
            var anchors = items.find('a');
            data.links = anchors.add(items.find('.'+prefix+'_item'));
            el.data('menu', data);
        }
        return data.links;
    };

    Plugin.prototype._outlines = function(state) {
        if (!state) {
            $('.'+prefix+'_item, .'+prefix+'_btn').css('outline','none');
        } else {
            $('.'+prefix+'_item, .'+prefix+'_btn').css('outline','');
        }
    };

    Plugin.prototype.toggle = function(){
        var $this = this;
        $this._menuToggle();
    };

    Plugin.prototype.open = function(){
        var $this = this;
        if ($this.btn.hasClass(prefix+'_collapsed')) {
            $this._menuToggle();
        }
    };

    Plugin.prototype.close = function(){
        var $this = this;
        if ($this.btn.hasClass(prefix+'_open')) {
            $this._menuToggle();
        }
    };

    $.fn[mobileMenu] = function ( options ) {
        var args = arguments;

        // Is the first parameter an object (options), or was omitted, instantiate a new instance
        if (options === undefined || typeof options === 'object') {
            return this.each(function () {

                // Only allow the plugin to be instantiated once due to methods
                if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + mobileMenu)) {

                    // if it has no instance, create a new one, pass options to our plugin constructor,
                    // and store the plugin instance in the elements jQuery data object.
                    $.data(this, 'plugin_' + mobileMenu, new Plugin( this, options ));
                }
            });

        // If is a string and doesn't start with an underscore or 'init' function, treat this as a call to a public method.
        } else if (typeof options === 'string' && options[0] !== '_' && options !== 'init') {

            // Cache the method call to make it possible to return a value
            var returns;

            this.each(function () {
                var instance = $.data(this, 'plugin_' + mobileMenu);

                // Tests that there's already a plugin-instance and checks that the requested public method exists
                if (instance instanceof Plugin && typeof instance[options] === 'function') {

                    // Call the method of our plugin instance, and pass it the supplied arguments.
                    returns = instance[options].apply( instance, Array.prototype.slice.call( args, 1 ) );
                }
            });

            // If the earlier cached method gives a value back return the value, otherwise return this to preserve chainability.
            return returns !== undefined ? returns : this;
        }
    };
}(jQuery, document, window));
```

- slicknav.min.css

```css
/*!
 * SlickNav Responsive Mobile Menu v1.0.10
 * (c) 2016 Josh Cope
 * licensed under MIT
 */.slicknav_btn,.slicknav_nav .slicknav_item{cursor:pointer}.slicknav_menu,.slicknav_menu *{box-sizing:border-box}.slicknav_btn{position:relative;display:block;vertical-align:middle;float:right;padding:.438em .625em;line-height:1.125em}.slicknav_btn .slicknav_icon-bar+.slicknav_icon-bar{margin-top:.188em}.slicknav_menu .slicknav_menutxt{display:block;line-height:1.188em;float:left;color:#fff;font-weight:700;text-shadow:0 1px 3px #000}.slicknav_menu .slicknav_icon{float:left;width:1.125em;height:.875em;margin:.188em 0 0 .438em}.slicknav_menu .slicknav_icon:before{background:0 0;width:1.125em;height:.875em;display:block;content:"";position:absolute}.slicknav_menu .slicknav_no-text{margin:0}.slicknav_menu .slicknav_icon-bar{display:block;width:1.125em;height:.125em;-webkit-border-radius:1px;-moz-border-radius:1px;border-radius:1px;-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);-moz-box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25)}.slicknav_menu:after,.slicknav_menu:before{content:" ";display:table}.slicknav_menu:after{clear:both}.slicknav_nav li,.slicknav_nav ul{display:block}.slicknav_nav .slicknav_arrow{font-size:.8em;margin:0 0 0 .4em}.slicknav_nav .slicknav_item a{display:inline}.slicknav_nav .slicknav_row,.slicknav_nav a{display:block}.slicknav_nav .slicknav_parent-link a{display:inline}.slicknav_menu{*zoom:1;font-size:16px;background:#4c4c4c;padding:5px}.slicknav_nav,.slicknav_nav ul{list-style:none;overflow:hidden;padding:0}.slicknav_menu .slicknav_icon-bar{background-color:#fff}.slicknav_btn{margin:5px 5px 6px;text-decoration:none;text-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.75);-webkit-border-radius:4px;-moz-border-radius:4px;border-radius:4px;background-color:#222}.slicknav_nav{clear:both;color:#fff;margin:0;font-size:.875em}.slicknav_nav ul{margin:0 0 0 20px}.slicknav_nav .slicknav_row,.slicknav_nav a{padding:5px 10px;margin:2px 5px}.slicknav_nav .slicknav_row:hover{-webkit-border-radius:6px;-moz-border-radius:6px;border-radius:6px;background:#ccc;color:#fff}.slicknav_nav a{text-decoration:none;color:#fff}.slicknav_nav a:hover{-webkit-border-radius:6px;-moz-border-radius:6px;border-radius:6px;background:#ccc;color:#222}.slicknav_nav .slicknav_txtnode{margin-left:15px}.slicknav_nav .slicknav_item a,.slicknav_nav .slicknav_parent-link a{padding:0;margin:0}.slicknav_brand{float:left;color:#fff;font-size:18px;line-height:30px;padding:7px 12px;height:44px}
```

Comment: does this have anything to do with the fact that you didn't close the head section (above the header to close the head)? (might want to add a body tag too)

Comment: Omitted from the post, but closed the head tag.

Comment: <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- Css Styles -->
    
</head>

<body>
<!-- Header Section Begin -->
   <header class="header-section">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <nav class="main-menu mobile-menu navbar">
                <ul>
                   <li class="nav-item active">
      <a href="/lmain" class="nav-link">Home</a>
   </li>